# Why do we use a single 'dash' for difference : $-$ and a double 'dash' for sum: $+$?

Tags: notation, math-history

Why do we use a single 'dash' for difference : $-$ and a double 'dash' for sum: $+$?

Just a shower thought: Who came up with this notation? It kind of makes it look like the difference is simpler than the sum, when intuitively, in my opinion, it should be the other way around.

Comment: But $+$ is two things joined together. If we take one away, we're left with $-$ (I'm just making things up).

Comment: Well, just my speculation, that a sum can be expressed as a difference of a negative number, so a difference may be more "elementary" as taking away  1 from 2 would require the use of $-$ but adding 1 to 2 can be written as $1-(-2)$.

Comment: '$=$' is also a double dash.

Comment: I recently read that $+$ originates from the leftover letter *t* of the word *et*, which is latin for *and*. Unfortunately, I cannot recall the source.

Comment: Wikipedia has Bjorn's suggestion and more in the article on history of mathematical notation.

Comment: (The product of) Two negatives make a positive? ;)

Comment: Also a good question for History of Science and Mathematics SE, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This set of web pages](http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathsym.html) is a good quick source of information on such topics, and I can add little to what is found there. It would not at all surprise me, however, if the abbreviation for Latin *et* mentioned there was a version of the very widespread [Tironian note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tironian_notes) used to abbreviate *et* throughout the medieval period and later. Some versions looked rather like this $7$, but others looked like a crossed $7$ and hence a bit like a plus sign. Here’s a picture of one such, taken from Wikipedia:

[image: Tironian note for ‘et’]

You can see how it might easily turn into $+$ if written hastily.